# How to remove an account from Google login options?

Tags: google-account, account-management, google-multi-login

When I am in the main screen where I get to choose which account, it does not give me the option to remove an account. When I click the arrow, it just signs into that account.

Comment: Ah. You don't actually want to delete an account. You're just looking to remove one of the options from the multi-logon screen, right? You need to log out of all accounts and then re-login to the ones you want. There was a similar question here recently. Let me see if I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

On the main screen, click "remove" (in the bottom) and then it will ask you which account to remove from the list (**x** marked next to it).